# How to produce a 3D density map of a time-depenent system of particles?

Tags: computational-physics, software, density, numerical-method

I have a time-dependent system of varying number of particles (~100k particles). In fact, each particle represents an interaction in a 3D space with a particular strength. Thus, each particle has $(X,Y,Z;w)$ which is the coordinate plus a weight factor between 0 and 1, showing the strength of interaction in that coordinate. [Here, I have uploaded 10 real-time snapshots](http://pho.to/9Ztti) of the system, with particles are represented as reddish small dots; the redder the dot, the stronger the interaction is.

The question is: how one can produce a 3D (spatial) density map of these particles, preferably in Matlab or Origin Pro 9 or [ImageJ](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/)? Is there a way to, say, take the average of these images based on the red-color intensity in ImageJ?

Since I have the numerical data for particles $(X,Y,Z;w)$ I can analyze those data in other software as well. So, you are welcome to suggest any other analytical approach/software.

Comment: Do you want to flatten the images (i.e., take this 3D and project it onto a 2D plane)?

Comment: I want 3D, but if it doesnt work out, I can project those information into a 2D plane. Are you thinking of a contour map?

Comment: Well a 3D density map really would be a contour map anyways. I just wanted to be clear on what you wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically looking for a *smoothing* algorithm, something that takes a collection of points and turns it into a density. This can be done with the help of a [*kernel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28statistics%29), a weighting function $K(u)$ that satisfies the following two conditions:
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} K(u)\,du=1 \\
K(u)=K(-u)\quad\forall u
\end{align}
The Wikipedia article I link lists many common functions that satisfy these conditions. Be warned: the resulting distribution *will* depend on the kernel you choose. I wrote a [Fortran 90 code](https://github.com/kylekanos/Smoothing) that does this for 2D distributions for some work I did during the PhD; I haven't tried it, but it should be easily extensible to 3D.

From here, the basic idea is the following: You take your continuous space and *discretize* it (turn it into discrete blocks). Then you run through your list of $(x,y,z)$ tuples and find the closest grid-cell to your tuple. When you do that, loop around the 1st nearest neighbors and see of this tuple can 'leak' into the adjacent cells--the comparing distances (`r < resolution` below) effectively is your [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)).

```
for each x,y,z in File
   iX <- closest(x)
   iY <- closest(y)
   iZ <- closest(z)
   for k=iZ-1,iZ+1
      for j=iY-1,iY+1
         for i=iX-1,iX+1
            r = sqrt((x-xgrid(i))^2 + (y-ygrid(j))^2 + (z-zgrid(k))^2)
            if r < resolution then
               map(i,j,k) = map(i,j,k) + kernel(r,resolution)
            end if
         end for
      end for
   end for
end for
```

where

- `closest` is a function finds the closest cell to that particular x,y,z value
- `xgrid` (and others) are cell-centered vectors that hold the values of the discrete grid
- `kernel` is the aforementioned kernel function; note that `u=r/resolution` for comparing the code to the kernel page functions
- `map` is the 3D vector that stores the density at each cell (probably safe to initialize it to some low value, e.g., 0 or 1e-10)

Other thoughts I had on this:

- You'll need to account for your weighting in the above, which probably will just be  `w*kernel`, though I'm not entirely sure on that.
- File output might also be tricky, as 3D density plots usually require some fancy formats; perhaps Matlab or Origin can handle such plots rather easily, I do not know.
- Edge cases (where the data point is right at the boundary) will be slightly tricky with the `iY-1` limits (some programs will wrap around to `iYmax` when negative numbers are reached), so you'll want to pick a domain that is completely outside the points.

Comment: This is a brilliant idea! But, suppose that I construct the `map` all over the space. Then, what is the best way to draw/plot/show/represent we  it visually? [Something like the density map in this figure](http://www.nature.com/ncomms/2013/130906/ncomms3414/fig_tab/ncomms3414_F3.html)

Comment: In my 2D code, I was able to use gnuplot. For your 3D, you'll likely have to save it in something like the [VTK format](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf) (NB: pdf) & use specialized software (e.g., LLNL's VisIt or ParaView). For those images, they probably also used specialized software for the 2D-to-3D deconvolution (but which one, I'm not sure).