# Are my few suppositions about how to transform particles into density mesh/grid correct?

Tags: computational-physics, density

I have a bunch of particles represented by their 3D coordinates. I want to transform them into a particle density grid.

- I am currently using an histogram code, *does it correspond to an interpolation to the nearest point (i.e. the center of each histogram cubelet)?*
- I've hear about linear (cloud-in-cells) interpolation, *is that kind of interpolation limited to the nearest cubelet?*
- I've also heard about smoothed-particle-hydrostatics-based interpolation, *is there any reference out there about the choice of the window?*
- Finally comes Voronoi-tesselation-based interpolation: *is it what it implemented in `scipy.interpolate.griddata`?*

I am aware that asking multiple questions like that is not usual here, but references on the internet are scarce and it seems to make sense to evoke all of these in a single place.

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194465/25301); it doesn't directly answer your questions here, but I think it would be useful reading as well.

Comment: For the last one, the scipy source code is available online ([see here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy)), so you probably can find out really quickly if it is using a tesselation based interpolation.